# Regex - Match multiple sequence of lines that contain the character pipe

Tags: regex, multiline

I have been trying to solve this regex problem for 2 days ...

I want to match values that could span multiple lines. The data must contain consecutive lines with one or more pipe characters. The idea is to convert each packet of lines to a table in Word.

See the below text sample:

```
dsfdqsf
dsfqds|dsfqds|qfsd|qdf
dsfqds|dsfqds|qfsd|dqsfq
dsfqds|dsfqds|qfsd|qdfvqs
dfq

dsfqds|dsfqds|qfsd|qdf
dsfqds|dsfqds|qfsd|dqsfq
dsfqdqs
```

Results would be the following

Match 1

```
dsfqds|dsfqds|qfsd|qdf
dsfqds|dsfqds|qfsd|dqsfq
dsfqds|dsfqds|qfsd|qdfvqs
```

Match 2

```
dsfqds|dsfqds|qfsd|qdf
dsfqds|dsfqds|qfsd|dqsfq
```

Anyone have any idea how to approach this problem?

This is only what I was able to produce :

[Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/OFdFa7/1/)

Comment: Something like `^[^\n|]*(?:\|[^\n|]*)+(?:\n[^\n|]*(?:\|[^\n|]*)+)*`? See https://regex101.com/r/Eulvg2/1

Comment: Indeed that answers the problem.
Thanks Wiktor for this solution.

Answer (score 3):

How about just

```
(?:.*?\|.*\n){2,}
```

[See this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/PFwp2E/1) (*newline* needed after last match).

If there is no *newline* after the last match, [replace `\n` with `(?:\n|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/nEIYoJ/1)

Comment: Simply perfect
(And I am enraged to find out that the answer was that simple ... shame on me)
Thank you little green dragon! (which reminds me of all those coins I spent in these arcade machines ^^)

Comment: @NLT hehee, sweet シ You welcome! Of course we loved bubble bobble ️

Comment: A tiny suggestion: insert `\r?` before `\n`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Interesting catch! Do you think `\r` wouldn't be matched by the dot? [Seet this demo](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxj7AI4CLS6W4pEjBVkEpLT8/pigmLymxSMmaiys1OSNfoaAoNT2@KLUgJzE5VUNdX08rJk9fXUdJSQekRxOmSikmTxcFxOSBTICZCzIUhnGaDDJWD27u//8A). Appreciate your comment, thank you :)

Comment: Interesting. I did not expect a dot to match`\r` but I see Ruby exhibits the same behaviour.